# How to bind an array of json objects to angular-dual-listbox with Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

Currently nothing this being displayed in source list,
the array of json is

```
[{deviceId: 101 , deviceName:"UK101"},
{deviceId: 102 , deviceName:"UK102"},
{deviceId: 103 , deviceName:"UK103"}]
```

I am currently making a service call to fetch this data,
My HTML code is

```
 <dual-list [key]="deviceId" [(display)]="deviceName" [source]="source" 
[(destination)]="target" height="150px"  ></dual-list>
```

But still no data is displayed in the lists

Comment: It's hard to tell what is wrong without seeing how and where you initialize your data. Could you provide a bit more relevant code from the component?

Comment: first confirm source prop you are providing here in dual-list tag i.e. [source]="source" have values (your array of object)

Comment: source contains the data that I have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after going through the issues in the github page of the developer.
The solution is I should only use [display] and [key] instead of [(display)] and[(key)] as I havent defined these two properties in the ts file

Answer (score 0):

in your ts file

```
myList = [{deviceId: 101 , deviceName:"UK101"},
{deviceId: 102 , deviceName:"UK102"},
{deviceId: 103 , deviceName:"UK103"}];
```

In your HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of  myList">
{{item.deviceId}}
</div>
```